# Extra blank page when converting HTML to PDF

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have created `PDF` from `UIWebView` like this :

```
UIPrintPageRenderer *render = [[UIPrintPageRenderer alloc] init];

[render addPrintFormatter:_webView.viewPrintFormatter startingAtPageAtIndex:0];

CGRect printableRect;
CGRect paperRect;
printableRect = CGRectMake(10, 5, kPaperSizeA4.width-20, kPaperSizeA4.height-10);
paperRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, kPaperSizeA4.width, kPaperSizeA4.height);
[render setValue:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:paperRect] forKey:@"paperRect"];
[render setValue:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:printableRect] forKey:@"printableRect"];

NSData *pdfData = [render printToPDF];
if (pdfData) {
     BOOL isSuccess = [pdfData writeToFile:aStrDocDirPath atomically:YES];
     if (isSuccess)
     {
         NSLog(@"Created and Saved");
     }
}
```

Now problem its add `blank page` in `created PDF`.

I refered [Extra blank page when converting HTML to PDF using abcPDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379521/extra-blank-page-when-converting-html-to-pdf-using-abcpdf). But in `iOS` how can we get rid of it???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changes accordingly:

Firstly `A4 size` was this:

```
#define kPaperSizeA4 CGSizeMake(595,842)
```

Changed it to :

```
#define kPaperSizeA4 CGSizeMake(595.2,841.8)
```

Now `increased` `page margin` of `content` in `PDF` :

```
printableRect = CGRectMake(10, 18, kPaperSizeA4.width-20, kPaperSizeA4.height-36);
```

Refer for more [Avoid extra blank page (with A4, in some unexpected cases](https://github.com/iclems/iOS-htmltopdf/pull/10)

Comment: No luck with this code change, didn't work for me... any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I got extra blank first page problem also when converting HTML to PDF. I was using FlyingSaucer for HTML to PDF conversion.

I had this CSS definition on my HTML:

```
@page Section1{
  size: 612.45pt 841.7pt;
}

div.Section1 {
  page: Section1;
}
```

The extra page was removed when I modified my CSS definition into:

```
@page {
      size: 612.45pt 841.7pt;
}
```