# extra page blank when converting HTML to PDF using Winnovative

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, pdf, winnovative

Hi I tried to convert an HTML to PDF with this structure:
first page with (page-break-after) and second page. 
If I attached the footer in every page I obtain an extra page blank. In order to verify if it's the content of the pages that ends in a new page I colored the background of my pages but I saw that the HTML content is in the first two pages, the third page is blank. There is a way to remove this page?

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
        <div id="paginauno" name="paginauno" style="width:100%; page-break-after:always;">
        .....
        </div>
        <div id="paginadue" name="paginadue" style="width:100%; background-color:red;">
        .....
        </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extra blank page when converting HTML to PDF using abcPDF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379521/extra-blank-page-when-converting-html-to-pdf-using-abcpdf)

Comment: I read this discussion but I use a different library

Comment: Cool.. Can you post the code related to the conversion. I think you need to  manually loop through the pages which has content and remove `page-break-after` after the last page which has content.